# How do you write a proper monte carlo simulation for a deck of cards in python?

Tags: python, simulation, montecarlo

So I want to write a monte carlo simulation for making card picks three times. Each time a card is picked, it is put back into the deck. The simulation for the three picks is to be run 100 times and I want to calculate the probability of picking a face card (King, Queen, Jack) for each pick. Is there a simpler way to do this besides listing cards? Here is my code:

```
#Letters `Q`, `K` and `J` represent king, queen and jack
def pickCard():
    return np.random.choice([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,'J','J','J','J'
                             ,'K','K','K','K', 'Q','Q','Q','Q'])
def checkPick(numTrials):
    numWins=0
    x=[]
    for i in range(numTrials):
        for j in range(3):
            d1 = pickCard()
            d2 = pickCard()
            d3 = pickCard()
            if (d1=='Q' or d1=='K' or d1=='J') and (d2 =='Q' or d2=='K' or d2=='J') and (d3 == 'Q' or d3=='K' or d3=='J'):
                numWins+=1
                break
    print('Probability of picking a face card =', numWins/numTrials)
checkPick(100)
```

Comment: If you're doing actual trials, why would you expect the same results every time?  Yes, the _overall_ probability is 12/52 * 12/52 * 12/52, but that's kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Also, why are you breaking out of the loop when you find three face cards?  Wouldn't you want to continue with the rest of the trials?

Comment: What’s the first pickCard() call doing?

Comment: @Bazingaa the first pickCard() returns a random selection from my 52 card list

Comment: @JohnGordon Okay thanks for the explanation. I am quite new to this and still trying to understand Monte Carlo. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. I was just wondering if there was a simpler way to do this or if I am on the right track.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added the break because I was concerned with only the first 3 picks in each simulation

Comment: I wonder what your goal is.  If as stated in the question "I want to calculate the probability of picking a face card (KQJ) for each pick" -- well, you know that already, right?  It's 0.0123.  What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am trying to accomplish this in python and discover different approaches to this using monte carlo simulation. It does seem redundant writing out all the cards in a list.

Comment: If you're trying to verify that the expected probability is borne out in real-world simulations, then I think you're on the right track.  Although I would use more than 100 trials.